# How to apply discrete Green's theorem to an image using the library Opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, fingerprint

I'm trying to implement the core detection algorithm on fingerprint from the paper "[Singular Point Detection in Fingerprint Image](http://staff.itee.uq.edu.au/lovell/aprs/accv2002/accv2002_proceedings/Zhang793.pdf)".

1) I have defined the direction field from part 2 (original and Theta, W=2x2)
[image: original and Theta]

2) The next step is to find the gradient of field orientation (over x and y respectively):

```
Mat Jx, Jy;
Sobel(theta, Jx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
Sobel(theta, Jy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

[image: Jx and Jy]

3) Apply next formula to image (disctete Green's theoreme):
[image: discrete Green's theoreme]

I do so, but I think it's wrong:

```
Mat Jx_dy, Jy_dx;
Sobel(Jy, Jy_dx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
Sobel(Jx, Jx_dy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);

Mat G, _G;
cv::subtract(Jy_dx, Jx_dy, _G);
integral(_G,G);
imshow("Jy_dx - Jx_dy", _G); //totally black image
```

How to apply this formula on image? 
Thanks.